FreeRTOS callback is not called
I'm writing some code for ESP32-S3 with ESP-IDF that uses FreeRTOS.
I create a simple task to read data from stdin and I want to invoke a callback after a reading.
Here's my code:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>

#include "tasks/task_nmea.h"

TaskHandle_t taskNMEAHandle = NULL;

void Task_NMEA_cb(char *line)
{
    printf(line);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    xTaskCreate(Nmea_Task, "task_nmea", 2048, &Task_NMEA_cb, 10, &taskNMEAHandle);
    while (1)
    {
        vTaskDelay(1);
    }    
}

task_nmea.h
#ifndef TASK_NMEA_H
#define TASK_NMEA_H

typedef void (*nmea_cb_t)(char *);
void Nmea_Task(void *arg);

#endif // TASK_NMEA_H

task_nmea.c
#include "task_nmea.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <driver/usb_serial_jtag.h>

#define NMEA_BUFFER_SIZE 256

char data[NMEA_BUFFER_SIZE];
nmea_cb_t callback;

void Nmea_Task(void *arg)
{
    callback = arg; // register callback
    usb_serial_jtag_driver_config_t usb_serial_jtag_config =
    {
        .rx_buffer_size = NMEA_BUFFER_SIZE,
        .tx_buffer_size = NMEA_BUFFER_SIZE,
    };

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(usb_serial_jtag_driver_install(&usb_serial_jtag_config));

    while (1)
    {

        int len = usb_serial_jtag_read_bytes(data, (NMEA_BUFFER_SIZE - 1), 20 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if (len)
        {
            // I used this function to be sure the chars are received!
            //usb_serial_jtag_write_bytes((const char *)data, len, 20 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            data[len] = '\0';
            callback(data);
        }

        vTaskDelay(1);
    }
}

If I send some chars on the stdin (using the JTAG/USB uart) it does not execute the callback (i.e. the line is not printed on stdout).
I read some questions about C calback (this and this for example) but I can't see my mistake.

You need to start the scheduler by calling vTaskStartScheduler. Before that tasks are not executed.

@0___________ no, I don't need to call vTaskStartScheduler. Please check https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/stable/esp32/api-reference/system/freertos.html#application-entry-point

The task is running: uncommenting the debug call it echoes back the incoming data

Have you tried calling usb_serial_jtag_write_bytes instead of printf in your callback, to see if you get the same result?

@ThomasJager tried right now. No output. However the debugger does not stop on the breakpoint placed inside the callback (but it stops at the callback invocation).

A task should have the following structure:
void vATaskFunction( void *pvParameters )
  {
     for( ;; )
  {
    -- Task application code here. --
 }

 Tasks must not attempt to return from their implementing
function or otherwise exit.  In newer FreeRTOS port
attempting to do so will result in an configASSERT() being
called if it is defined.  If it is necessary for a task to
exit then have the task call vTaskDelete( NULL ) to ensure
its exit is clean. */
vTaskDelete( NULL );
}

I don't see any vTaskDelete in your Task code.
What is the purpose of while loop with vTaskDelay when you are creating the task?

There's no vTaskDelete since I don't need to stop the task: it will run forever. The while loop after creating the task is the main loop of my application. It's empty to provide a minimal example. I don't see any difference from my code.
